# Unable to schedule job in oozie. Getting Error while creating HiveContext

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, oozie, oozie-workflow

Trying to run a spark job from oozie. Below is the code which I am trying to run.

```
SparkConf conf = getConf(appName);
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
HiveContext hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
JOB[0000000-170808082825775-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-170808082825775-oozie-oozi-W@Sample-node] Launcher exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
```

Here's my workflow xml file

```
<workflow-app name="DataSampling" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
    <start to='Sample-node'/>
    <action name="Sample-node">
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
                        <configuration>
                                <property>
                                        <name>tez.lib.uris</name>
                                        <value>/hdp/apps/2.5.3.0-37/tez/tez.tar.gz</value>
                                </property>
                        </configuration>
            <master>${master}</master>
            <mode>${mode}</mode>
            <name>Sample class on Oozie - Sampling</name>
            <class>Sampling</class>
            <jar>/path/jarfile.jar</jar>
            <arg>${numEventsPerPattern}</arg>
            <arg>${eventdate}</arg>
            <arg>${eventtype}</arg>
            <arg>${user}</arg>
        </spark>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="fail"/>
    </action>
   <kill name="fail">
        <message>Workflow failed, error
            message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]
        </message>
    </kill>
    <end name='end'/>
</workflow-app>
```

I am using Hortonworks Data Platform 2.5. Can any one please help if I am missing some thing in the classpath.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some more error stack added:

Caused by: org.datanucleus.api.jdo.exceptions.ClassNotPersistenceCapableException: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MDatabase" is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it worked. Oozie is able to create HiveContext.

Issue is with classpath. Delete the folder `/user/oozie/share/lib` in hdfs.

Update the following properties in Ambari under `core-site.xml`
Set the following properties to `*`

```
hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.groups
hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.hosts
hadoop.proxyuser.root.groups
hadoop.proxyuser.root.hosts
```

Created new shared library using the following command:

```
/usr/hdp/current/oozie-client/bin/oozie-setup.sh sharelib create -fs /user/oozie/share/lib
```

Restart oozie service

Above 2 steps should be done using `oozie` user

Added the following tags to work flow xml file

```
<spark-opts>--num-executors 6 --driver-memory 8g --executor-memory 6g</spark-opts>
```

Run the oozie job as `hdfs` user.